# Puppeteer: TypeError: page.waitForXpath is not a function

Tags: mocha.js, puppeteer, ui-automation, chai

I am using this code. Output of the code always shows ****TypeError: page.waitForXpath** is not a function**. Puppeteer version: 8.0.0 and puppeteer-xpath version: 0.1.0  I have also used this command to upgrade: npm install https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/     but that does not work. Here is my code:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var browser, page;
before(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    devtools: false,
    args: [
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process",
        "--window-size=1920,1080"
    ]
 });
 page = await browser.newPage();
})
describe("Search to google", async () => {
  it("write something to searchbar", async () => {

    await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
    let searchBarSelector = '[name=q]';
    await page.waitForSelector(searchBarSelector);
    let [searchBarElement] = await page.$$(searchBarSelector);
    await searchBarElement.type("JavaScript Tutorial");
    // await page.type(searchBarSelector,"JavaScript Tutorial");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");

    let imageXpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Images')]";
    await page.waitForXpath(imageXpath);
    let imageTextElement = await page.$x(imageXpath);
    expect(imageTextElement != null).equals(true);


  })
})
after(async () => {
   await browser.close();
})
```

Output: [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just have a typo: it is `page.waitForXPath()`, not `page.waitForXpath()`.

See [page.waitForXPath(xpath[, options])](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) in the docs.

Comment: invalid response as of 02072024